# Branch.io - iDevAffiliate Integration

Tags: branch.io, affiliate

I have a question regarding mobile tracking.
We currently use branch.io for mobile tracking (IOS, Android) and we would like to use iDevAffiliate for our affiliate network. Does someone has experience here with the integration / tracking possibilities?
Branch.io has already integration to Affise, Everflow - so it should be possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow. Avoid saying things like, `thanks in advance`, It doesn't add value to your question. Try and include things that you've tried, or ideas that you have, to add value to your post. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question

Comment: You can also ask here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/